# DataContractJsonSerializer doesn't work with formatted JSON?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, json

When using the `DataContractJsonSerializer` to deserialize JSON, if the input has tabs in it (formatted JSON) then the serializer throws an exception (shown below). If I replace all of the spaces, tabs and new-lines with "", the serializer is able to deserialize it just fine.

What's the deal?

#### Exception

```
System.MemberAccessException: Cannot create an abstract class.
at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.nativeGetUninitializedObject(RuntimeType type) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(Type type) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatReaderGenerator.UnsafeGetUninitializedObject(Int32 id) 
at ReadBaseSearchElementFromJson(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString[] ) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonClassDataContract.ReadJsonValueCore(XmlReaderDelegator jsonReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonDataContract.ReadJsonValue(XmlReaderDelegator jsonReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns) 
at ReadSearchElementsFromJson(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString , CollectionDataContract ) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonCollectionDataContract.ReadJsonValueCore(XmlReaderDelegator jsonReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonDataContract.ReadJsonValue(XmlReaderDelegator jsonReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns) 
at ReadSearchGroupFromJson(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString[] ) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonClassDataContract.ReadJsonValueCore(XmlReaderDelegator jsonReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonDataContract.ReadJsonValue(XmlReaderDelegator jsonReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract dataContract, String name, String ns) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(Stream stream)
```

#### Formatted JSON

This **does not** deserialize, throwing the exception above.

```
{
    "Mode":"And",
    "Elements":
    [
        {
            "Name":"ID",
            "Operator":"Equal",
            "Value":"3"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Non-formatted JSON

This **does** deserialize.

```
{"Mode":"And","Elements":[{"Name":"ID","Operator":"Equal","Value":"3"}]}
```

#### Update

I've posed a [sample solution](http://cid-0ede5d21bdc5f270.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/Forums/StackOverflow/JsonTest.zip) which exhibits this problem.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?  Because I'm currently facing the same issue.

Comment: The only solution I've come up with is to replace spaces and new-lines with nothing. Not really a solution, I know, but in my case it works okay. Please let me know if you come up with something better!

Comment: @JoshM. Note that my answer of just removing the whitespace before the `"__type"` allows you to preserve almost all of your formatting.  If this meets your needs, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of your formatting is actually fine.  You just can't have any whitespace between `{` and `"__type"`.

See this previous answer: [JSON deseralization to abstract list using DataContractJsonSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971271/json-deseralization-to-abstract-list-using-datacontractjsonserializer)

**So for instance, your sample code is trying to deserialize this JSON string:**

```
"{\r\n\t\"Mode\":\"And\",\r\n\t\"Elements\":\r\n\t[\r\n\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\"__type\":\"SearchParameter:#JsonTest.Search\",\r\n\t\t\t\"Name\":\"LastName\",\r\n\t\t\t\"Operator\":\"Equal\",\r\n\t\t\t\"Value\":\"Smith\"\r\n\t\t},\r\n\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\"__type\":\"SearchGroup:#JsonTest.Search\",\r\n\t\t\t\"Mode\":\"Or\",\r\n\t\t\t\"Elements\":\r\n\t\t\t[\r\n\t\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"__type\":\"SearchParameter:#JsonTest.Search\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"Name\":\"FirstName\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"Operator\":\"Equal\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"Value\":\"Tim\"\r\n\t\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"__type\":\"SearchParameter:#JsonTest.Search\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"Name\":\"FirstName\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"Operator\":\"Equal\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"Value\":\"Tom\"\r\n\t\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t\t]\r\n\t\t}\r\n\t]\r\n}"
```

Formatted:

```
{
    "Mode":"And",
    "Elements":
    [
        {
            "__type":"SearchParameter:#JsonTest.Search",
            "Name":"LastName",
            "Operator":"Equal",
            "Value":"Smith"
        },
        {
            "__type":"SearchGroup:#JsonTest.Search",
            "Mode":"Or",
            "Elements":
            [
                {
                    "__type":"SearchParameter:#JsonTest.Search",
                    "Name":"FirstName",
                    "Operator":"Equal",
                    "Value":"Tim"
                },
                {
                    "__type":"SearchParameter:#JsonTest.Search",
                    "Name":"FirstName",
                    "Operator":"Equal",
                    "Value":"Tom"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Change it to this, and the error goes away:**

```
"{\r\n\t\"Mode\":\"And\",\r\n\t\"Elements\":\r\n\t[\r\n\t\t{\"__type\":\"SearchParameter:#JsonTest.Search\",\r\n\t\t\t\"Name\":\"LastName\",\r\n\t\t\t\"Operator\":\"Equal\",\r\n\t\t\t\"Value\":\"Smith\"\r\n\t\t},\r\n\t\t{\"__type\":\"SearchGroup:#JsonTest.Search\",\r\n\t\t\t\"Mode\":\"Or\",\r\n\t\t\t\"Elements\":\r\n\t\t\t[\r\n\t\t\t\t{\"__type\":\"SearchParameter:#JsonTest.Search\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"Name\":\"FirstName\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"Operator\":\"Equal\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"Value\":\"Tim\"\r\n\t\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t\t{\"__type\":\"SearchParameter:#JsonTest.Search\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"Name\":\"FirstName\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"Operator\":\"Equal\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"Value\":\"Tom\"\r\n\t\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t\t]\r\n\t\t}\r\n\t]\r\n}"
```

Formatted:

```
{
    "Mode":"And",
    "Elements":
    [
        {"__type":"SearchParameter:#JsonTest.Search",
            "Name":"LastName",
            "Operator":"Equal",
            "Value":"Smith"
        },
        {"__type":"SearchGroup:#JsonTest.Search",
            "Mode":"Or",
            "Elements":
            [
                {"__type":"SearchParameter:#JsonTest.Search",
                    "Name":"FirstName",
                    "Operator":"Equal",
                    "Value":"Tim"
                },
                {"__type":"SearchParameter:#JsonTest.Search",
                    "Name":"FirstName",
                    "Operator":"Equal",
                    "Value":"Tom"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yep - the answer was to not use any spaces. Which is annoying! Seems like a bug to me. Oh well. Maybe the WebAPI handles this better.

Comment: This is rediculous. Why can't we use white spaces in a JSON object? Looks like DataContractJsonSerializer is not the good choice at all.

Comment: @MilesChen Well I believe *most* whitespace is OK, just not immediately before the special "__type" property.  (Which still seems like a bit of a silly requirement, but isn't *too* onerous, IMO.)

Answer (score 1):

Weird. You may want to try JSON.NET, a nice library for JSON serialization and deserialization. I've used it in a project recently and it worked in cases where the DataContractJsonSerializer had failed.

You can find it at http://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks Roy, I'd prefer to stick to framework assemblies since what I'm doing is not that complex and "should" work. I hope I've just missed something.

Comment: Is it not better to use canned, existing, open-source solutions rather than spend hours and hours trying to shoehorn the .NET Framework around it? Just my 2 cents...

Comment: Sure, it can be - if the framework simply won't do what I want - but I have a feeling it's just something I'm missing.

Answer (score -1):

That's weird as the following works great for me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;

public class SomeModel
{
    public string Mode { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Element> Elements { get; set; }
}

public class Element
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var json =
@"{
    ""Mode"":""And"",
    ""Elements"":
    [
        {
            ""Name"":""ID"",
            ""Operator"":""Equal"",
            ""Value"":""3""
        }
    ]
}";
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(SomeModel));
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(json)))
        {
            var model = (SomeModel)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
            Console.WriteLine(model.Mode);
            foreach (var element in model.Elements)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(element.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(element.Operator);
                Console.WriteLine(element.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case both "SomeModel" and "Element" derive from a base type. I'm going to post a code sample now.

Comment: @Josh M., yes, it would be nice when asking a question to always post some code allowing to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I understand that and I try to post the important code but sometimes it is just too much to post in a clear manner. Thats why I've created a sample project and attached it to my question. I know it's not the generally accepted method but for a problem which relies on multiple classes, it's the only clear way to convey the issue.

Comment: @Josh M., that's the reason why the first step when you encounter a problem is to try isolating it into an easily reproducible application. And by the way if you get into the habit of always doing this you will find out that you no longer need to ask questions on StackOverflow as you will solve the problems by yourself :-)

Comment: Posting on SO is my last option after I've spent hours trying to solve a problem. So it's not always the case that isolating the problem will allow me to solve it without an additional pair of eyes. I'm not looking for someone to "google" an answer for me here (like others tend to do), it's genuine confusion.